# How to unbind views in Kotlin/Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, view, unbind

How do you unbind a view in Kotlin for Android, and/or properly dispose of view elements for fragments and custom views in onDestroy/onDestroyView?

In Java/Android, you might do your cleanup in onDestroy() or onDestroyView() for fragments, setting null to the view elements or using something like Unbinder.unbind() if you were using ButterKnife.

Syntax restrictions seem to prevent setting view elements to null in onDestroyView().

```
private lateinit var contents: ViewGroup

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, container, false)
contents = root.bind(R.id.contents) // calls a findViewById,   (purposefully not using the view id cache)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
// What do I do here?
contents = null // syntax error
super.onDestroyView()
}
```

`

Is clean up of view elements required in Kotlin?

Comment: Cleanup of view elements is not required in either Java or Kotlin, in general. So long as you have no global references to views, everything should be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: Great thanks, I couldn't find any official Android documentation stating that. Might be useful to link to it if it exists.

Comment: @CommonsWare cleanup in fragments is required in some cases, usually if they can be detached/attached multiple times - for example in `FragmentViewPager`.